# Emerging MessageBox while processing data

Tags: wpf-controls

I am working with C# and a WPF project.

I created a button that, when clicked, process information that generally can last less than 3 minutes; during that time I would like to show a message box indicating: "This process will last less than 3 minutes, please wait", then when the process finishes I would like to supress the message box automatically. Is this possible? How can I get this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, why not start the long running task using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and report progress?: [WPF Multithreading: Using the BackgroundWorker and Reporting the Progress to the UI](http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/).

In fact, WPF has it's own mechanism called the Dispatcher: [Build More Responsive Apps With The Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)